# PHP ob_get_contents is empty

Tags: php, caching, ob-get-contents

I am using ob_start() and ob_get_contents() to setup a cache. It all works fine on my Windows desktop test machine, but when I run it on the live host ob_get_contents() is empty. The print data is derived from a series of php includes. When I dont call the includes, just add the html output directly, it works on the live host, so its nothing to do with the buffer itself. The output is 20K or so.

So I a guessing its something to do with the host setup.

I have no idea where to start looking, can anybody point me in the right direction.

Caching Code not included as its standard stuff, and it works fine if the output is included directly rather than subject to a series of PHP includes.

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

well thats very strange. I moved the cache creation code to a slightly later stage in page creation and it all worked fine. There must be something in my code thats emptying the buffer. Anyway happy now !